# How to handle "puts 'Found!' if User.where(id: 0)" in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Take a look at these codes.

```
pry> puts User.find_by(id: 0) ? 'Found!' : 'Not found'
Not found

pry> puts User.where(id: 0) ? 'Found!' : 'Not found'
Found!
```

The first one is ok but the second one `User.where(id: 0)` returns an empty Array which is evaluated as `true` in an if condition clause in Ruby.

I know there are some ways to avoid this problem. One of them is using `empty?` or `present?` method when you try to fetch "multiple rows" like:

```
users = User.where(country: 'vietnam')

if users.empty?
  ...
```

I think it's ok to use `empty?` or `present?`. But when you try to fetch a single row, you don't have to use such methods because when there is no row, it returns `nil`.

What I'm worried about is that sometimes you need `empty?` and sometimes you don't need `empty?`. Then the codes becomes hard to read.

So I thought it might be good that I always use `empty?` whether a method returns multiple rows or a single row. But now I don't want to see `empty?` methods all over my codes.

Is there any good way to handle this?

Answer (score 2):

They are different methods and have different return values. I'm not sure what your use case is but if your only purpose is to show `found` or `not found` then you could use [exists?](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class). Using `present?` or `blank?` is completely fine though.

```
User.exists?(id: 0) ? 'Found!' : 'Not found'
#=> "Not Found"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.where(id: 0)
```

replace it with

```
User.where(id: 0).first
```

Comment: Sorry `id: 0` is just an example. What I want to do is like `country: 'vietnam'`. I can't use `first` method here because I want to fetch all the rows. But I still need to write `empty?` here because there might be no row.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to try to resolve non-existing problem. It is *convenient* to return empty array rather than *falsey*, because in the real world *the result is to be operated on*. That said, immediately after you got the results, you probably want to, say, show them. To *avoid* redundant checks, you already have an array on hand and you do not need to care whether there were any records returned, or not:

```
User.where(id: 0).each do |u|
  puts "Found the user: #{u}"
end.tap do |us|
  puts "No one user found" if us.empty?
end
```

The code above prints the message about none user found, but typically the second part is not necessary. If one omits last 2½ lines (starting from `tap`,) nothing will be printed and in most cases this is a desired result.

Comment: Exactly... I'm actually converting a system written in PHP into Rails. This problem may stem from the bad design of the old PHP codes. Thank you.